# Sending messages from Spring Boot service not going to subscribed Angular client connected via WebSocket/WebStomp

Tags: angular, spring-boot, messaging, stomp

I have a project that uses a backend Spring Boot server using Spring messaging and websockets to communicate with an Angular frontend that's using STOMP (via WebStomp).

To set some base knowledge, we're using **/comixed** as our application prefix, and **/topic/**, **/queue/** and **/secured/** as our prefixes for the simple broker.

I can (and do) see subscriptions come from the frontend to the backend. For example:

```
this.subscription = this.webSocketService.subscribe(
      '/comixed/taskcount',
      frame => {
        const message = JSON.parse(frame.body) as TaskCountMessage;
        this.logger.debug('Task message:', message);
        this.store.dispatch(
          setTaskCount({
            count: message.count
          })
        );
      }
    );
```

causes a breakpoint in the following method:

```
@SubscribeMapping("/taskcount")
public List<TaskCountMessage> subscribeToTaskCounts() {...}
```

to fire.

But when I try to publish messages to the subscribed client from another part of the application at a later time using:

```
    this.messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(
        "/topic/taskcount", new TaskCountMessage(this.workerTaskAdaptor.getTaskCount()));
```

nothing ever arrives to the subscribed client. I've enabled debugging in WebStomp and I see where the client is subscribing to the topic:

```
[DEBUG]: Subscribing to topic: /comixed/taskcount
10:27:33.292 web-socket.service.ts:47 [DEBUG]: [STOMP] >>> SUBSCRIBE
id:sub-1615476453292-968
destination:/comixed/taskcount
```

So I'm not sure why messages aren't flowing from the backend to the frontend. Is it an issue with using "/topic/"? I can't really find any clear help on what's the difference in STOMP and Spring between those prefixes, when to use them and when not to. I'm familiar with messaging concepts, but this one is really confusing me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

(edit)

While I did manage to finally get things flowing for this use case (by having both the publisher and the subscriber use **/topic/taskcount**), I added another use case that doesn't work at all.

I added a method that returns some data on initial subscription:

```
  @SubscribeMapping("/scantypes")
  public List<ScanTypeMessage> getScanTypes() {
    log.info("Getting all scan types");
    return this.scanTypeService.findAll().stream()
        .map(scanType -> new ScanTypeMessage(LibraryAction.ADD, scanType))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

This method *ONLY* gets invoked if the subscriber uses **/comixed/scantypes**. If I use **/topic/scantypes**, similar to the previous use case, then it does not work.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong or misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

So what I ended up doing was to change the destination string used to when publishing to "/topic/taskcount", and change the frontend to subscribe to "/topic/taskcount". Then it started working.

But, while this works, I'm not sure I understand why nothing has the prefix (in my case "/comixed") in front of it? I thought this was necessary since it's how the broker is configured:

```
public class ComiXedWebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(final MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/comixed");
  }
```

Can anybody maybe explain that, or give better suggestions for names to use?

Comment: The "/comixed" is the prefix for the STOMP requests from client to server. For example, if you annotate an endpoint method  with @MessageMapping("send"), you will be send requests from client to "/comixed/send".

Comment: @jzProg So, if I understand you correctly, what you're saying is that, if I don't specific a root (if I exclude anything starting with "/" in the destination), then the messaging library will prepend "/comixed/" to it?

Comment: what i mean is that you would use this prefix only if you wanted to send a request from client to server. The client need to subscribe to "topic" , in order to listen messages from server.

Comment: @jzProg I guess I'm not understanding the point of it. I tried changing my code to have the client subscribe to "/comixed/topic/taskcount" and the server publishing to "topic/taskcount", which didn't work, then to "taskcount", which didn't work. In the end using "/topic/taskcount" in both places is the only thing that worked. Then I added a method with @SubscribeMapping("/scantypes") but THAT only gets invoked if I do a subscribe to "/comixed/scantypes". So I'm TOTALLY confused.

Comment: In your example, the client should listen to "topic/taskcount" and the server need to publish to "topic/taskcount". But, if you wanted e.g to send a request from client to server in order to be received from all the subscribers of a topic lets say "topic/message", you will make a request to "comixed/send" and then the server will publish to the "topic/message".

Comment: For the above, you need to have a method "send", annotated with @MessageMapping("send") and @sendTo("topic/message") ( or manually call inside method body:  this.messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/message",....) , if you omit @send )